# Service Bus unknown error (0xffffffff) while sending message

Tags: c#, azureservicebus

I have an Azure App Service API which connects to a Service Bus Queue. Everything worked perfect for a while, but then I started to get these kind of errors:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Unknown error (0xffffffff) ErrorCode: SocketError) ---> Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.ServiceBusCommunicationException: Unknown error (0xffffffff) ErrorCode: SocketError ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Unknown error (0xffffffff)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.ServiceBusConnection.CreateConnectionAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.FaultTolerantAmqpObject`1.OnCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.GetOrCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.GetOrCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpLinkCreator.CreateAndOpenAmqpLinkAsync()
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageSender.CreateLinkAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.FaultTolerantAmqpObject`1.OnCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.GetOrCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.GetOrCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageSender.OnSendAsync(IList`1 messageList)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageSender.OnSendAsync(IList`1 messageList)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.RetryPolicy.RunOperation(Func`1 operation, TimeSpan operationTimeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.RetryPolicy.RunOperation(Func`1 operation, TimeSpan operationTimeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageSender.SendAsync(IList`1 messageList)
```

```
    public async Task SendAsync(string message)
    {
        var queueMessage = new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message));
        var queueClient = GetQueueClient("myqueue");
        await queueClient.SendAsync(queueMessage);
    }

    public IQueueClient CreateQueueClient(string queueName)
    {
        var messageBusSection = _configuration
            .GetSection("AppSettings:MessageBus");
        var connectionString = messageBusSection["ConnectionString"];
        var path = messageBusSection.GetSection("Queues")[queueName];
        return new QueueClient(connectionString, path);
    }
```

I assume this is not a quota exceeded issue and it also doesn't say timeout. Any idea on how I could debug this?

Comment: Looks like you may need Microsoft support on this one.

Comment: The connection probably closed.  Try from cmd.exe get list of tcp connections >Netstat -a   When connection fails you can see status to determine the connection state.  You can also check Event Viewer to see if there are any errors when connection failed.

Comment: Have you tried updating your project to the latest version of the service bus nuget packages?  Perhaps they have made breaking changes.  Shouldn't be, but it's not like it has never happened before in Azure.

Comment: While renewing a client is far from ideal, don't think this is a connection limitation. If the client reaches the limit, the exception will be a different one (`QuotaExceededException`). This does look as an issue between your WebAPI and Azure Service Bus broker. What you should do is a few things: 1) Cache your client or the connection used to construct it (not connection string). 2) Prior to using the client, inspect `IsClosedOrClosing` to verify you can use it.

Comment: After making QueueClient singleton, this never happened. It's been over 7 months, number of requests exponentially grew and this problem never occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: This is not certain to solve your problem (since the error is not very descriptive).

One of the best practices in using ASB messaging is to [reuse factories and clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements#reusing-factories-and-clients):

> It is recommended that you do not close messaging factories or queue,
> topic, and subscription clients after you send a message, and then
> re-create them when you send the next message.

It's possible that you're just running into some sort of connection throttling that could be solved by reusing the `QueueClient` instead of re-creating it on every message send.

Comment: I am sending the message once per HTTP request. Do you recommend a Singleton queue client ?

Comment: @kord Yes, reusing the `QueueClient` through some sort of Singleton would prevent connections from being established on every message that is sent.

Comment: Changing it to Singleton fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just started getting lots of these yesterday myself:

> Microsoft.ServiceBus: Unknown error (0xffffffff)

And

> Could not connect to net.tcp://some-namespace.servicebus.windows.net:9354/. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:00. TCP error code -1: Unknown error (0xffffffff).

As you see the connection attempt fails directly.

Have been working fine for months, then bam.... I guess Microsoft did something again. Their Azure Status board is all green, but I have a 60% failure rate on my function.

Comment: Indeed. After looking more into the logs, I've noticed same error message when accessing third party APIs through http. And yeah, Azure status dashboard was all green.